# Formatar tabs de um menu em HTML

Tags: html, css, formatação

Eu criei uma *tab* mas gostaria de fazer umas pequenas alterações que não consigo.

Queria substituir essa zona por exemplo por circulos em vez de texto:

[image: exemplo do pretendido]

Como consigo fazer isso?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //Default Action
  $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
  $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
  $(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content

  //On Click Event
  $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
    $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
    $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
    $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content
    var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the rel attribute value to identify the active tab + content
    $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active content
    return false;
  });

});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
ul.tabs {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  height: 32px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
  border-left: 1px solid #999;
  width: 100%;
}
ul.tabs li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 31px;
  line-height: 31px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-left: none;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  background: #F0F0F0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
ul.tabs li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  padding: 0 20px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  outline: none;
}
ul.tabs li a:hover {
  background: #ccc;
}
html ul.tabs li.active,
html ul.tabs li.active a:hover {
  background: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
.tab_container {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-top: none;
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
  -khtml-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
  -khtml-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}
.tab_content {
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
.tab_content h2 {
  font-weight: normal;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #ddd;
  font-size: 1.8em;
}
.tab_content h3 a {
  color: #254588;
}
.tab_content img {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h1>teste</h1>
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#tab1">Heading 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tab2">Heading 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tab3">Heading 3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tab4">Heading 4</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tab5">Heading 5</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab_container">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab_content">
      <h2>Heading 1</h2>
      <p>Content 1</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab_content">
      <h2>Heading 2</h2>
      <p>Content 2</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab3" class="tab_content">
      <h2>Heading 3</h2>
      <p>Content 3</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab4" class="tab_content">
      <h2>Heading 4</h2>
      <p>Content 4</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab5" class="tab_content">
      <h2>Heading 5</h2>
      <p>Content 5</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ver também no [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hvgh1px9/).

Comment: Editei um pouco seu Fiddle, veja se é esse o resultado que você gostaria: https://jsfiddle.net/hvgh1px9/4/  (Como você não forneceu muitos detalhes de como queria que fosse... editei o que você tinha para chegar ao resultado agora, observe as partes de comentários `/* MODIFICADO */`, no código).

Comment: Desconfigurada? Verifique se está carregando tudo corretamente (caminhos), aconteceu algum erro em seu console? (F12 / Chrome);

Comment: Não entendi o que estava a acontecer mas já consegui por a funcionar. Muito Obrigado

Comment: Legal, e as tabs funcionaram como você queria?

Comment: Sim, eu consigo controlar a altura de cada tab? 
Pois as vezes tenho textos um pouco maiores e queria saber se era possivel

Comment: Acredito que ele vai se ajustar automaticamente..., você pode fazer um teste?

Comment: exato, ele ajusta automaticamente conforme o texto.

Comment: Uma duvida. É possivel colocar dentro da tab no canto inferior direito uma tab a dizer: "Saber mais" com um link

Comment: Uma `tab` **dentro** de **outra** `tab`? Ou só um link dentro da tab no canto inferior?

Comment: O link fica so no texto "Saber mais".

Comment: Não entendi muito bem ainda o que você gostaria de fazer, mas você pode utilizar `<a href="seudestino">Saber mais</a>` e adicionar alguma estilização para ele ficar no canto direito.

Comment: @RafaelWithoeft dá para criar uma resposta com a resolução do problema?

Comment: @JorgeB. claro, já faço a resposta :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Face ao teu código atual, o que precisas é de aplicar alguma formatação via CSS para manipular o aspeto dos elementos até atingires o que pretendes.

- **Preparação base**

  Primeiro, fazemos uso de algumas propriedades de CSS para definir um aspeto base aos elementos que queremos passar para círculos:

  ```css
  /* retirar aspeto de link */
  text-decoration: none;
  outline:0 none;

  /* passar link para bloco de linha, esconder texto dentro do mesmo */
  display: inline-block;
  text-indent:-9999px;
  overflow:hidden;

  /* definir um tamanho */
  width:14px;
  height:14px;

  /* aplicar cores */
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color:#fff;
  ```
- **Passar elementos quadrados para redondos**

  Podemos recorrer à propriedade [`border-radius`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius) para arredondar os cantos de um elemento, onde a partir de determinado valor estamos efetivamente a deixar o elemento circular.

  Site para demonstração: http://border-radius.com/

  ```css
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  ```

  <sup>50% permite dizer: arredondar os cantos até metade da largura de cada lado, logo, um quadrado fica um circulo.</sup>
- **Sombreado no fundo do elemento**

  Podemos recorrer à propriedade [`box-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) para aplicar uma sombra num elemento. A posição da sombra face ao elemento, bem como se é por fora ou por dentro do mesmo são algumas das opções disponíveis.

  Site para demonstração: http://www.cssmatic.com/box-shadow

  Para o exemplo em baixo usei:

  ```css
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px -2px 4px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px -2px 4px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  box-shadow: inset 0px -2px 4px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  ```

  <sup>- `inset` para ficar do lado de centro.</sup>
  <sup>- `0px -2px` para ficar horizontalmente ao centro e verticalmente a surgir de baixo.</sup>
  <sup>- `4px 0px` para efeito *blur* com 4 pixeis sem propagação.</sup>
  <sup>- `rgba(0,0,0,0.75)` cor preto com 25% transparência.</sup>

O que vimos em cima, foi a passagem dos teus links que eram os retângulos para uns círculos pequeninos:

- **Antes**

  [image: Captura de tela, aspeto anterior]
- **Depois**

  [image: Captura de tela, aspeto atual]

## Exemplo

Elaborei um exemplo e aproveitei para otimizar parte do teu código, mas deverás proceder aos ajustes que entendas necessários caso ainda não esteja 100% como pretendido.

Exemplo também disponível no [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zuul/j7rrvdcj/).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".tab_content").hide();

  $(".tabs li:first").addClass("active").show();
  $(".tab_content:first").show();

  $("ul.tabs li").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $this = $(this);

    $(".tabs .active").removeClass("active");
    $(".tab_content").hide();

    var activeTab = $this.addClass("active").find("a").attr("href");
    $(activeTab).fadeIn();
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
ul.tabs,
ul.tabs li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul.tabs {
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
  height: 32px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
ul.tabs li {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
  line-height: 32px;
  text-align: center;
}
ul.tabs li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: 0 none;
  display: inline-block;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
ul.tabs a:hover,
ul.tabs .active > a {
  background: red;
  border-color: transparent;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px -2px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px -2px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: inset 0px -2px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
.tab_container {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-top: none;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
}
.tab_content {
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
.tab_content h2 {
  font-weight: normal;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #ddd;
  font-size: 1.8em;
}
.tab_content h3 a {
  color: #254588;
}
.tab_content img {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h1>teste</h1>

  <ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#tab1">1</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#tab2">2</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#tab3">3</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#tab4">4</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#tab5">5</a>

    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab_container">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab_content">
      Conteúdo da tab 1
    </div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab_content">
      Conteúdo da tab 2
    </div>
    <div id="tab3" class="tab_content">
      Conteúdo da tab 3
    </div>
    <div id="tab4" class="tab_content">
      Conteúdo da tab 4
    </div>
    <div id="tab5" class="tab_content">
      Conteúdo da tab 5
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Editei seu código original e as alterações podem ser vistas pelos comentários de **/* MODIFICADO */**;

https://jsfiddle.net/hvgh1px9/7/

A principal alteração foi feita no javascript, que no caso é o seguinte trecho:

```
/* MODIFICADO */
//Alteramos a tab
window.setInterval(function() {
    var index = $('.tabs > .active').next('li').index() +1;
    if (index == 0) {
       $("a[href=#tab1]").trigger('click');
    } else {
        $("a[href=#tab"+index+"]").trigger("click");
    }
}, 2000);
/* FIM MODIFICADO */
```

Em um intervalo de 2 segundos, verificamos qual é a tab ativa.
Então você vai me perguntar, o que significa esse trecho: `if (index == 0) {` ?

Executando essa parte: `$('.tabs > .active').next('li').index()` ele sempre pegará o próximo índice de um li e quando não existir próximo, retornará -1. Que no caso somado ao +1, ficará 0; Então quando o índice for 0, saberemos que é a primeira tab que deverá ser exibida novamente... caso contrário continuará ativando as demais tabs.

Em questão de layout, retirei os nomes das tabs do html (Heading 1, Heading 2...) e adicionei o seguinte `CSS` para mostrar pequenos círculos nos headers das tabs:

```
/* MODIFICADO */
/* Adicionamos o círculo no link da tab*/
ul.tabs li a:after {
    content: '\25CF';
} 
/* FIM MODIFICADO */
```